# Calculate distance using speed of sound

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

I've been working on learning Java and this was a challenge as part of a chapter on data types:

> Create a program that computes how far away, in feet, a listener is
>   from a sound. Sound travels approximately 1,100 feet per second
>   through air.
>
> You can also compute the distance to a large object, such as a rock
>   wall, by timing the echo. For example, if you clap your hands and time
>   how long it takes for you to hear the echo, then you know the total
>   round-trip time.
>
> *Java: A Beginner's Guide, Sixth Edition - by Herbert Schildt · McGraw-Hill Education (Chapter 2)*

I'm super-new to OOP and am trying to nip bad habits in the bud, so-to-speak. I've divided the logic in one class as much as I think is possible (at my current skill level).

**SoundSpeed.java**

```
public class SoundSpeed {
    private final double SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED = 1100;
    public double timeInSeconds;
    public boolean isEcho;
    private int distanceDivisor;

    double getResult() {
        if(isEcho) {
            distanceDivisor = 2;
        } else {
            distanceDivisor = 1;
        }
        return (timeInSeconds * SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED) / distanceDivisor;
    }
}
```

**SoundSpeedCalc.java**

```
class SoundSpeedCalc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SoundSpeed soundSpeed = new SoundSpeed();
        soundSpeed.timeInSeconds = 35.079;
        soundSpeed.isEcho = true;
        String verb;

        if(soundSpeed.isEcho) {
            verb = "echo";
        } else {
            verb = "travel";
        }
        System.out.println("The sound took " + soundSpeed.timeInSeconds + " seconds to " 
        + verb + " and thus the distance is " + soundSpeed.getResult() + " feet away.");
    }
}
```

Example output (using above parameters in `main`):

> The sound took 35.079 seconds to echo and thus the distance is 19293.45 feet away.

Example output if I set `soundSpeed.isEcho` to `false`:

> The sound took 35.079 seconds to travel and thus the distance is 38586.9 feet away.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you *want* to do is simply

```
public static double distanceBySounding(double seconds, boolean isEcho) {
    return (isEcho ? 0.5 : 1.0) * seconds * 1100 /* ft. per second */;
}
```

The question is, how should this function be expressed in an object-oriented way?  It's pretty safe to say that this…

```
SoundSpeed soundSpeed = new SoundSpeed();
soundSpeed.timeInSeconds = 35.079;
soundSpeed.isEcho = true;
System.out.println(soundSpeed.getResult());
```

… is an unpalatable interface.  Manipulating public instance variables like that is not only cumbersome, it is an unsound practice (pardon the pun).  Given a choice between the two options above, I would much prefer the simpler function to the contorted object.  And that's fine.  Java allows you to write code that doesn't fully conform to OOP.

---

What if you wanted an object-oriented design?  The key to object-oriented design is that you want to model objects.  That means that you have to find plausible objects to model — the more realistic, the better.  What's a SoundSpeedCalc?  [I don't know; you can't buy one.](http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=SoundSpeedCalc)  But you can sure [buy a sonar](http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=sonar)!  It makes sense to instantiate a `Sonar` with its configuration parameters (the sound medium and its active/passive mode), then you can start "aiming" it at stuff by calling `.distance()`.

```
public class Sonar {
    public enum Medium {
        AIR(1100);

        private final double ftPerSec;

        Medium(double ftPerSec) {
            this.ftPerSec = ftPerSec;
        }
    }

    private final Medium medium;
    private final boolean isEcho;

    public Sonar(Medium medium, boolean isEcho) {
        this.medium = medium;
        this.isEcho = isEcho;
    }

    public double distance(double seconds) {
        return medium.ftPerSec * seconds / (isEcho ? 2 : 1);
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use it effectively:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double seconds = 35.079;
    boolean isEcho = true;

    Sonar sonar = new Sonar(Sonar.Medium.AIR, isEcho);
    String verb = isEcho ? "echo" : "travel";
    System.out.printf("The sound took %s seconds to %s and thus the distance is %s feet.\n",
                      seconds, verb, sonar.distance(seconds));
}
```

Note the use of `System.out.printf()` as a nicer alternative to string concatenation.  Also, I've used conditional expressions — it's a perfect way to assign one of two values depending on a boolean switch.

Comment: OP's "object oriented" approach reminds me of my AP Computer Science class. Not correct or practical, but enough to teach the basics of objects

Comment: @ColeJohnson: indeed, the problem with these examples often is that by removing any substantial content that might obscure the view of the OOP techniques involved, you end up with a problem so trivial that it's very difficult to justify throwing any kind of technique at it all, and the resulting code is ridiculous ;-) More realistically, the value of these abstractions can be seen in the test harness, since that shows all major uses of it. If your ambition is just a function that multiplies its input by 1100 then you've already lost, we need interesting requirements to write interesting code!

Comment: +1 Love the point to model real objects. All too often we lose track of this point. I would prefer an interface and final implementations for `MEDIUM` over an enum for extensibility purposes.

Answer (score 16):

## Does a result by any other name smell as sweet?

- The name `timeInSeconds` might be expressed just as well as `seconds`.
- The usual name of `SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED` is `SPEED_OF_SOUND`
- `SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED` might benefit from a comment stating the units and any other assumptions:

  ```
  /* approximate, feet/second at sea level */
  ```
- `getResult` could use a more descriptive name.  Perhaps `feet` would do.

## To instance or not to instance, that is the question

The `SoundSpeed` might not need to be instantiated.  It might be fine as just a place to hold the `SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED` constant, and a `static` function to do the calculation:

```
public class SoundSpeed {
    private final double SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED = 1100;
    public static double feet(double seconds, boolean isEcho) {
        double feet = seconds * SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED;
        if(isEcho)
            feet = feet / 2;
        return feet;
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree with your first line.  Never call a variable or parameter by its units.  time would be acceptable, as would elapsedTime, travelTime or other variation on that concept.  Exception: If you're doing unit conversions, then units would be acceptable parameter names.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I thought we were doing unit conversions.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, why not? I have multiple references that *including* the unit of measurement in the variable name is a good habit.

Comment: Let's look at the function call: feet(double seconds, boolean isEcho)  What does it return?  feet?  No. it returns a distance.  What parameter does it take? It takes a time.  You can make them more explicit, such as distanceTravelled and sonarPingTime.   Units should be part of the API documentation, or more robustly, as a parameter such as Units.SECONDS

Comment: @ChrisCudmore If the meaning of the variables are clear in their context, _and_ changing them would require adding comments to communicate the same intent, then that rule is hurting the code, not helping it.  However, I do agree that making units explicit--by using a unit library, or having a unit parameter, is often better.

Answer (score 13):

- `SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED` should also be `static`:

  ```
  private static final double SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED = 1100;
  ```

  This is because it's not owned by a particular class instance.
- The other data members should still be `private`:

  ```
  private double timeInSeconds;
  private boolean isEcho;
  ```

  This applies to all classes in general.
- The calculations in `getResult()` can be simplified with a ternary statement:

  ```
  distanceDivisor = (isEcho) ? 2 : 1;
  ```

  The same thing can be done with `verb`'s assignment in `main()`.

Comment: I tried to set those two as private but I got compiler errors when I ran SoundSpeedCalc... `The field SoundSpeed.timeInSeconds is not visible`, etc.  Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: @Phrancis: That's because you're setting its value after declaring an instance, so it wouldn't be allowed to modify that `private` field.  You should construct `soundSpeed` with that value instead.

Comment: "`SOUND_TRAVEL_SPEED` should also be static:" this would preclude the usage of this class underwater for SONAR.

Answer (score 8):

Just one thing:

Do not have a boolean field that begins with `is`. Like this one:

```
public boolean isEcho;
```

(200_success and others is right that this should not be `public`)

In Java, the naming conventions for boolean *getters* are that they should begin with `is`, followed by the name of the variable they are a getter for. So let's say this variable were to have a getter:

```
public boolean isIsEcho() {
    return this.isEcho;
}
```

Now that just sounds strange!

The correct naming convention for the variable and its getter method is:

```
private boolean echo;

public boolean isEcho() {
    return this.echo;
}
```